# How to persist to a SQL Server table as a .NET agent for someone else?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

Suppose I have a .NET service that receives requests (i.e. messages over a messaging system) from clients (i.e. users running a .NET GUI application) and writes them to a table in SQL Server. What is the best way to write to a table from a .NET app that performs the role of an agent (i.e. processes requests from someone else) so that I capture who truly sent the message?

Here's what I thought about:

- I was thinking of creating a connection to SQL server as the user that sent me the message and write to the table (impersonation). The **PROBLEM**: I would need the user's password which they won't be willing to send to me.
- I could update a field in the table with the user's name and also write the data. The **PROBLEM**: that isn't secure as the agent could have a bug where it puts the wrong username.

Is there a fool-proof design to do this in .NET?

Comment: I think you need to expound on your problem a little more - this is pretty vague.  Who/what are your clients?  In lieu of using impersonation you may have to settle with some type of PKI

Comment: We have a similar situation in that requests that come in from the UI are simply put on a queue for later processing by a completely different process. We have a message base class that, when instantiated, grabs the requesting user's identity and sticks it in the message. The property is read-only and it's set by the base class message constructor.

Comment: what are your expectations/requirements? do you have any **realistic** issue that prevent you from using the second solution? no, the chance of a bug is not something that should restrain your choices because bugs may happen everywhere in the code.

Comment: If you expect a bug, just fix the bug. Second solution should be the right one, You dont need user password.